How to redirect to Laravel from logged in diffrent website?
I'm having a scenario that i want to logged in from my pure PHP website, then i click on a logo in my website and it will redirect to Laravel website with 'auto-login' with previous user credential. Is there anyway to make sense with this?
I'm using Laravel 11 with laravel sanctum.
i've tried this solution: i'll redirect to /login route of laravel with some encrypted data of that user, then in loginController in laravel i will decrypt data and check user in users table, if it exists i will create access token (sanctum) then redirect to my front-end page as logged in user.

On your pure PHP website, create a function to encrypt user credentials and redirect to the Laravel application.
// Function to encrypt data
function encryptData($data, $key)
{
    $iv = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($data), 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}

// User data to be encrypted
$userEmail = 'example@example.com';
$userPassword = 'password123';

$userData = ['email' => $userEmail, 'password' => $userPassword];
$encryptionKey = 'your-secret-key'; // Use a secure key
$encryptedData = encryptData($userData, $encryptionKey);

// Redirect to the Laravel application with encrypted data
$laravelAppUrl = 'https://your-laravel-app.com/external-login';
header('Location: ' . $laravelAppUrl . '?data=' . urlencode($encryptedData));
exit();

Set up the endpoint: Set up a new method and handler method in Laravel to handle external programs. and Decrypting data
// routes/web.php
Route::post('/external-login', [ExternalLoginController::class, 'login'])->name('external.login');

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ExternalLoginController extends Controller
{
// Function to decrypt data
function decryptData($data, $key)
{
list($encrypted, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2);
return json_decode(openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv), true);
}
public function login(Request $request)
{
$encryptedData = $request->input('data');
$decryptionKey = 'your-secret-key';

$decryptedData = decryptData($encryptedData, $decryptionKey);

$user = User::where('email', $decryptedData['email'])->first();

if ($user && Hash::check($decryptedData['password'], $user->password)) {
Auth::login($user);

$token = $user->createToken('external-login')->plainTextToken;

return redirect()->route('home')->with('token', $token);
}

return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['login' => 'Invalid credentials.']);
}
}

